# App scoped user ids

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have two facebook applications with their own access tokens.

I have followed [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business#field) guide to create a business and associate the aforementioned apps to this business.

I now have a token for business from doing a graph api call -

```
/me?fields=token_for_business
```

When doing a regular api call without referencing this token for business, I can return `app scoped user ids` who have been invited to events for example like so -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{FaceBookGroupID}/invited?access_token={MyAppsAccessToken}
```

Where `MyAppsAccessToken` varies depending on the app, thus resulting in different app scoped user ids being returned depending on what access token is used.

After getting the `token_for_business` I updated my call to -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{FaceBookGroupID}/invited?token_for_business={MyTokenForBusiness}&access_token={MyAppsAccessToken}
```

My assumption was that now the applications are associated to the same business and have a link token, the calls would have brought back the same user ids in the JSON response, however this is not the case and regardless of appending the `token_for_business` parameter to the url, the same JSON responses are returned as the first call.

Is it possible to return the same user ids with two different access tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, different Access Token means different App, means different App Scoped ID. You can only use the Token for Business to match different App Scopes.

Btw, the call with `token_for_business` as parameter does not make any sense. The token is for one user.

Comment: Sigh, I had hoped that wasn't the case, however thanks for highlighting this, shall mark as correct answer when I can.